# RXJS 6.0 : ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs-compat/_esm5/add/operator/publishReplay.js

Tags: angular, rxjs, migration, angular6, rxjs6

After Migration of my application from angular 5 to 6, rxjs have been causing all sorts of issues. I used rxjs-compact during migration process and after removing it, since it cause greater memory utilization. I have been left with errors like this.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs-compat/_esm5/add/operator/publishReplay.js
>   Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/training/Desktop/vishnu/TemplateAppv6/node_modules/rxjs-compat/_esm5/add/operator/publishReplay.js'

I have tried importing publishReplay from rxjs and rxjs/operators.

import { filter, map, catchError, publishReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

But issues still persists, is there any change for publishReplay like catchError.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ErrorResponse } from '../core/interfaces/Error';

import { throwError, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, catchError, publishReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HomeConstants } from './home-consatant';
import { BaseService } from '../core/base.service';




                // Construct the rail data.
                responses.map((response: RailResponse) => {
                  railsData[response.railId] = response
                    .entries
                    .map((entry: EntriesEntity) => {
                      return {
                        imageSrc: this.getImageUrl(entry, response.railId), // Get rail image according to the rail type.
                        contentTypeLabel: entry.pricingType, // Content Type.
                        description: entry.title, // Rail title.
                        url: '/details/' + entry.programType + '/' +
                          this.utility.encodeProgramName(entry.title) + '/' + entry.id, // Rail url.
                        isPopoverVisible: true,
                        popoverTitle: entry.title,
                        popoverDescription: entry.title
                      };
                    });
                });
                return railsData;
              })
              .publishReplay(1, this.cacheInterval)
              .refCount()
              .take(1)
              .catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(res));
            this.rails.set(railParams[0].railId, this.railResponse);
          }
          return this.rails.get(railParams[0].railId);
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why is this downgrade! I suppose it's a valid question,since the answer for my question is not available. Please edit the question or explain what's wrong with rather than downgrading.

Comment: I upvoted, because I believe this is indeed a valid question.

Comment: Try removing `rxjs-compat` because it's for some reason trying to import `publishReplay` from a wrong path.

Comment: I removed it at the first place soon after migration @martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Finally I found out the issue and solved, I hope it will help some else so I am posting it here.

The issue was with arrangement of sub function of pipe function. Since the new rxjs supports only pipe method, every sub-function which we used to give to map function using '.' we have to put the sub-function with ','.

```js
.map((entry: EntriesEntity) => {
                      return {
                        imageSrc: this.getImageUrl(entry, response.railId), // Get rail image according to the rail type.
                        contentTypeLabel: entry.pricingType, // Content Type.
                        description: entry.title, // Rail title.
                        url: '/details/' + entry.programType + '/' +
                          this.utility.encodeProgramName(entry.title) + '/' + entry.id, // Rail url.
                        isPopoverVisible: true,
                        popoverTitle: entry.title,
                        popoverDescription: entry.title
                      };
                    });
                });
                return railsData;
              })
              .publishReplay(1, this.cacheInterval)
              .refCount()
              .take(1)
              .catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(res));
            this.rails.set(railParams[0].railId, this.railResponse);
          }
```

change this to ..

```js
 .pipe(map((response: GetRailsResponse) => {
        return response;
      }),
      publishReplay(1, this.cacheInterval),
      refCount(),
      take(1),
      catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse)=> { 
        return throwError(res)
        })
      );


      this.rails.set(JSON.stringify(requestBody), this.railsRes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 upgrades the version of RxJS to the one with lettable operators. You can no longer use the syntax that you used to unless you install the compatibility package.

New syntax is something like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

let squares: Observable<number> = of(1, 2).pipe(
  map(m => m * m)
);
```

Compatibility package: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat)

There is also an automatic way to convert your source code to the new (& IMHO crappy) syntax.

Comment: I think you are asking me to do this
 .pipe(publishReplay(1, this.cacheInterval))    But error still persists

Comment: After doing the above code, it's showing the error pipe is not defined.

Comment: Here please check.. @kubal5003